# How do I detect shake while movie is playing?

Tags: iphone, shake

I have an iphone app where I am able to shake and play a random file with MPMoviePlayerController. But while the Movie Player is on the screen, it is unable to detect a shake. How can I get the Movie Player to detect shakes while playing?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Only the "first responder" recieves the UIResponder shake notifications. Use UIAccelerometer directly; Googling "UIAccelerometer shake" should give you some vaguely working code.